# Mixing by aux out to aux in

Tags: mixing, noise

Say, I have a laptop, a desktop, and a headset.

Instead of investing $40 on a dedicated mixer, I was thinking of buying a 3.5mm male-male aux cable and pass through a slave(desktop audio out) to the master(laptop microphone audio in) to my headset.

Sound coming from desktop(slave) will be limited to notification(facebook messenger, email...). Sound coming from laptop(master) will vary(music, youtube...)

Here are my assumptions.

1. This method will work with some sound deterioration.
2. Sound source coming from master won't deteriorate.
3. Sound source coming from slave will emit continuous(?) noise, thereby the mixed result will have continuous noise.
4. Slave will be mono, master will be stereo.

Am I correct on all these assumptions? Are there more disadvantages of my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.This method will work with some sound deterioration.

There will be significant [latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(audio)) if you're using default drivers (non-asio)

2.Sound source coming from master won't deteriorate.

Neighter one should sound different if cables and soundboards are of good quality (magnetically shielded)

3.Sound source coming from slave will emit continuous(?) noise, thereby the mixed result will have continuous noise.

You might get some ground humming especially in laptops due to poor grounding in most of them

4.Slave will be mono, master will be stereo.

If you have a stereo cable, both will be stereo